# Sudden Random Error

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code,

```
Sub AddZeroes()
'Declarations
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, endrow As Long
'Converts the A column format to Text format
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
'finds the bottom most row
endrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
'selects the top cell in column A
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
'loop to move from cell to cell
For i = 1 To endrow - 1
            'Moves the cell down 1. Assumes there's a header row so really starts at row 2
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            'The Do-While loop keeps adding zeroes to the front of the cell value until it hits     a length of 7
Do While Len(ActiveCell.Value) < 7
                            ActiveCell.Value = "0" & ActiveCell.Value
            Loop
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

And it adds preceding zeroes to numbers and converts them to text to make them 7 charecters long if they are less than 7. ANd it has been working all day and suddenly it has stopped. I Keep getting the error RUN TIME ERROR 6 OVERFLOW. I am at a loss because it has worked without any issues all day up until now. It keeps highlighting the portion:

```
For i = 1 To endrow - 1
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: you don't need the "Do ... Loop" to add zero's onto the front of the number. `Activecell.value = right(Activecell.value, string$(7,"0"),7)` will do that in one statement. Also, to avoid the `select` statement, I would change your entire loop to: `for i=2 to endrow-1:cells(i,1)=right(cells(i,1), string$(7,"0"),7):next`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this line:

```
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, endrow As Long
```

To be this instead:

```
Dim i As Long, j As Long, endrow As Long
```

Integer variables can only go up to 32,767.  If your row numbers are higher than that, you need to use Long.